# Can we ask on law community for the laws about relationship?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask on law community for the laws about relationships?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by this? Most (all?) law is about relationships - people and other people, people and the government, companies, etc.

Comment: i mean to say can i ask for the laws about kiss, s*x and etc? and these words are allowed or not here? what if someone flag my question with containing adult words?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned, questions about the law that contain words that *might* be taboo in some cultures - sex, kiss, etc - are allowed, as long as they are on-topic.

Having these in your title *might* limit its audience (e.g. some words are blacklisted from the Hot Network Questions list).

You might find that you can express your question without these words, but alone, they are not enough to render a post offensive.